# ANTLR4: Get end position of a context

Tags: python-3.x, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to get start and end position (line and column) of a context in ANTLR4. I'm working with [this](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python3/Python3.g4) Python3 grammar. I wrote a listener, that prints start and end line:

```
class MyListener extends Python3BaseListener {
    @Override
    public void enterFuncdef(@NotNull Python3Parser.FuncdefContext ctx) {
        Token start = ctx.getStart();
        System.out.print("start: ");
        System.out.print(start.getText());
        System.out.print(": ");
        System.out.println(start.getLine());

        Token stop = ctx.getStop();
        System.out.print("stop: ");
        System.out.print(stop.getText());
        System.out.print(": ");
        System.out.println(stop.getLine());
    }
}
```

My test input:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

def iterative_factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        result *= i
    return result
```

My listener prints

```
start: def: 1
stop: DEDENT: 0
start: def: 7
stop: DEDENT: 0
```

but I expect

```
start: def: 1
stop: DEDENT: 5
start: def: 7
stop: DEDENT: 11
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to accomplish 280Z28's first proposal:

```
grammar Python3;

...

@lexer::members {

  ...

  // The most recently produced token.
  private Token lastToken = null;

  ...

  @Override
  public Token nextToken() {

    // Check if the end-of-file is ahead and there are still some DEDENTS expected.
    if (_input.LA(1) == EOF && !this.indents.isEmpty()) {

      // First emit an extra line break that serves as the end of the statement.
      this.emit(new CommonToken(Python3Parser.NEWLINE, "\n"));

      // Now emit as much DEDENT tokens as needed.
      while (!indents.isEmpty()) {
        this.emit(createDedent());
        indents.pop();
      }
    }

    Token next = super.nextToken();

    if (next.getChannel() == Token.DEFAULT_CHANNEL) {
      // Keep track of the last token on the default channel.
      this.lastToken = next;
    }

    return tokens.isEmpty() ? next : tokens.poll();
  }

  private Token createDedent() {
    CommonToken dedent = new CommonToken(Python3Parser.DEDENT, "DEDENT");
    dedent.setLine(this.lastToken.getLine());
    return dedent;
  }

  ...
}

...

NEWLINE
 : ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' ) SPACES?
   {
     ...

     if (opened > 0 || next == '\r' || next == '\n' || next == '#') {
       ...
     }
     else {
       ...

       if (indent == previous) {
         ...
       }
       else if (indent > previous) {
         ...
       }
       else {
         // Possibly emit more than 1 DEDENT token.
         while(!indents.isEmpty() && indents.peek() > indent) {
           this.emit(createDedent());
           indents.pop();
         }
       }
     }
   }
 ;

...
```

The changes are:

- there is a `lastToken: Token` inside the lexer that keeps track of the most recent emitted token which gets set inside the `nextToken()` method;
- the two places that created a new instance of a dedent-token now use `createDedent()` where a dedent token is created with the same line number as `lastToken`.

View the exact changes in this commit: https://github.com/bkiers/python3-parser/commit/1a1118f8f540843ebc2d6bb2a76c56f894869b93

The complete grammar can be found here: https://github.com/bkiers/python3-parser/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/nl/bigo/pythonparser/Python3.g4

which prints:

```
start: def: 1
stop: DEDENT: 5
start: def: 7
stop: DEDENT: 11
```

for your input.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't expect, that it is that tricky. I added column information in createDedent: 
`dedent.setCharPositionInLine(this.lastToken.getCharPositionInLine() + this.lastToken.getText().length() + 1);`
Do you think, this will work in every case?

Comment: I realized 2 errors in my approach of adding column information (in the comment above). First, omit `+ 1`, because getCharPositionInLine is zero-based. Second, emitted tokens contain text, that isn't present in the source code. Therefore, I calculate the length of the last token based on his start and stop index. To be able to keep regular and custom emitted tokens apart, I set start and stop index of emitted tokens to `-1` ([as described](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Token.html#getStartIndex()) in the Token interface).

Answer (score 1):

The last token matched by the `funcdef` rule (counting descendant rules it calls) is a `DEDENT` token. The `DEDENT` token is not produced by a lexer rule, but by an action in the overridden `nextToken()` method. The code which creates the `DEDENT` tokens does not assign any position information, presumably since they are not actually part of the input. There are two ways to solve this.

1. Assign position information to the `DEDENT` tokens when they are created. This information would likely be a zero-width token following the last character of the last true input token preceding the `DEDENT` token.
2. Write your own implementation of `getStop()` method, which ignores all `DEDENT` tokens to ensure only tokens with proper position information get returned.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to implement 1., but where or how can I get position in the lexer?